# There is anyway use Oauth in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon

I'm use Oauth2 devloping for browser enxtension,but Oauth is only support for chrome.So there is any way use Oauth2 support dor firefox extension ?

Comment: I resolved this issue, do you still need help with it?

Comment: I need help on this. Can you help me at this, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608064/error-processing-manifest-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment90182051_51608064