# Error processing manifest in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have developed a extension primarily focused on chrome which works but now i need that extension to work in firefox either so I checked by loading the extension by going to about:debugging page and loading temporary addons. Currently, I go an error. I got error something like this

> Reading manifest: Error processing options_page: An unexpected
>     property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
>
> Reading manifest: Error processing oauth2: An unexpected property 
>     was found in the WebExtension manifest.
>
> Reading manifest: Error processing key: An unexpected property was 
>     found in the WebExtension manifest.

Here is what my manifest file looks like(I removed options_page)

manifest.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "Browser Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description":
        "This extension allow the user to select the text and redirect to the application",
    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Select Text",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/browser16.png",
        "48": "img/browser48.png",
        "128": "img/browser128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["extension/js/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://mail.google.com/mail/*/*",
                "http://mail.google.com/mail/*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["extension/js/jquery.min.js", "extension/js/content.js"],
            "css": ["extension/css/main.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "webNavigation",
        "notifications",
        "cookies",
        "identity",
        "*://mail.google.com/mail/*/*",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/*",
        "https://*.googleusercontent.com/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["img/browser128.png", "img/ios-link.svg"],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id":
            "114446495690-8ejpdgvmn8vc9pblteupetas.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": ["profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"]
    },
    "key":
        "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnqFjzbt+LtejD1JhOyMUbejOHdLoemzryr+ZQHK2CEKuI0yVVYToFs7eNusH/hfxhnyF27G4BU8apsTc695EpVQGD0ANKdt6BjubRnA/4VcdkmfdD3D9nsdCc+fHkINRU5e05grfs/BETWW/JAUULduaNWGfhT7"
}
```

How do i resolve above issues to make it firefox compatible as well?

Comment: Remove "key", use "options_ui". As for "oauth2", it's not supported, as well as getAuthToken method, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity).

Comment: If i need to use gmail api then it cannot be compatible for firefox addon. Because i need that oauth2 for gmail api.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider opening an issue on bugzilla site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sure, I will